# How to process file content differently for each line using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a file which has this data -

```
view:
  schema1.view1:/some-path/view1.sql
  schema2.view2:/some-path/view2.sql
tables:
  schema1.table1:/some-path/table1.sql
  schema2.table2:/some-path/table2.sql
end:
```

I have to read the file and store the contents in different variables.

```
viewData=$(sed  '/view/,/tables/!d;/tables/q' $file|sed '$d')
tableData=$(sed  '/tables/,/end/!d;/end/q' $file|sed '$d')
```

echo $viewData

```
view:
  schema1.view1:/some-path/view1.sql
  schema2.view2:/some-path/view2.sql
```

echo $tableData

```
tables:
  schema1.table1:/some-path/table1.sql
  schema2.table2:/some-path/table2.sql
```

```
dataArray=("$viewData" "$tableData")
```

I need to use a for loop over dataArray so that I get all the components in 4 different variables.

Lets say for $viewData, the loop should be able to print like this -

```
objType=view
schema=schema1
view=view1
fileLoc=some-path/view1.sql
objType=view
schema=schema2
view=view2
fileLoc=some-path/view2.sql
```

I have tried sed and cut commands but that is not working properly. And I need to do this using shell script only.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Each array element in `dataArray` is a multi-line string. For looping over it, you have to split the string on the newlines. A completely different approach would be to make `viewData` and `tableData` arrays, and  store into `dataArray` not the data itself, but the **names**  of those arrays: `dataArray=(viewData tableData)`. When you loop over the array names, you can then use a nameref to access the content of the "nested" arrays.

Comment: A vastly superior approach would be to have your data in a standard format like JSON or YAML so you don't have to keep reinventing ad-hoc parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**remark:** If you add a space character between the `:` and `/` in the input then you would be able to use YAML-aware tools for parsing it robustly.</sup>

Given your sample input you, can use this `awk` for generating the expected blocks:

```bash
awk '
    match($0,/[^[:space:]]+:/) {
        key = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
        val = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        if (i = index(key,".")) {
            print "objType=" type
            print "schema=" substr(key,1,i-1)
            print "view=" substr(key,i+1)
            print "fileLoc=" val
            printf "%c", 10
        } else
            type = key
    }
' data.txt
```

```
objType=view
schema=schema1
view=view1
fileLoc=/some-path/view1.sql

objType=view
schema=schema2
view=view2
fileLoc=/some-path/view2.sql

objType=tables
schema=schema1
view=table1
fileLoc=/some-path/table1.sql

objType=tables
schema=schema2
view=table2
fileLoc=/some-path/table2.sql
```